# Demeaned Matrix representation help please

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics

Let 
$\mu= A
  \begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{1}{n} \\
    \frac{1}{n}\\
    ...\\
    \frac{1}{n}\\
  \end{bmatrix}$

Let $\hat{a_1},...,\hat{a_k}$ be the demeaned- versions of $ A = a_1,...,a_k$ and define $\hat{A}$ as the $n$ x $k$ matrix $\hat{A} = [\hat{a_1} ... \hat{a_k}]$.

How do I write a matrix expression for $\hat{A}$ in terms of $A$ and $\mu$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $I_n$ be the identity matrix and $J_n$ the all-ones matrix of dimension $n$, i.e. $\;(I_n,J_n) \in {\mathbb R}^{n\times n}$

Then the de-meaned matrix is
$$\eqalign{
\hat A &= A-\frac{1}{n}J_nA \\
 &= \left(I_n-\frac{J_n}{n}\right)A  \\
 &= C_nA  \\
}$$
where $C_n$ is called the [Centering Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centering_matrix).

You can also write it as
$$\hat A = A - {\tt1}\mu^T$$
where ${\tt1}\in{\mathbb R}^n$ is the all-ones vector.